# "module “QtQuick” is not installed" (Android porting)

Tags: android, c++, qt, porting, qt5.4

I'm trying to porting my application to android with qt5.4 but I have this error:

*W/Qt      (30916): qrc:/qml/FrontEnd.qml:1 ((null)): qrc:/qml/FrontEnd.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" is not installed*

This is my .pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = sandbox-build-android

QT+= qml quick widgets printsupport xml svg

INCLUDEPATH += [...]# my include path

# Input
HEADERS += [...] # my include
SOURCES += [...] # my source

RESOURCES += ../sandbox/resources.qrc

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../edalab/else-datamodel-classes/build-buildAndroid-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_0-Debug/ -lbuildAndroid

INCLUDEPATH += [...]
DEPENDPATH += [...]

contains(ANDROID_TARGET_ARCH,armeabi-v7a) {
    ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = [..]
}

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
```

This is my deployment.pri:

```
android-no-sdk {
    target.path = /data/user/qt
    export(target.path)
    INSTALLS += target
} else:android {
    x86 {
        target.path = /libs/x86
    } else: armeabi-v7a {
        target.path = /libs/armeabi-v7a
    } else {
        target.path = /libs/armeabi
    }
    export(target.path)
    INSTALLS += target
} else:unix {
    isEmpty(target.path) {
        qnx {
            target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
        } else {
            target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
        }
        export(target.path)
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}

export(INSTALLS)
```

In my FrontEnd.qml I have this import:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
```

I don't see any substantial difference from .pro of example project that work properly on Android.

**UPDATE**

I saw another example “Calendar” and I noticed that I was missing this flag “ OTHER_FILES “ so I added all the paths of my QML files to it but the problem persists.

I also retrieved the apk from my smartphone and I have extracted the contents. I noticed that my apk didn't include some libraries that are present in the apk sample that works:

> libqml_Qt_labs_folderlistmodel_libqmlfolderlistmodelplugin.so
>   libqml_Qt_labs_settings_libqmlsettingsplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQml_Models.2_libmodelsplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQml_StateMachine_libqtqmlstatemachine.so
>   libqml_QtQuick.2_libqtquick2plugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Controls_libqtquickcontrolsplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Controls_Styles_Android_libqtquickcontrolsandroidstyleplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Dialogs_libdialogplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Dialogs_Private_libdialogsprivateplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Layouts_libqquicklayoutsplugin.so
>   libqml_QtQuick_Window.2_libwindowplugin.so

**My project directory structure**

```
.
├── Project1
│   ├── file.pro
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── sub1
│   │   │   ├── file1.hh
│   │   │   └── sub1.1
│   │   │       └── file2.hh
│   │   └── sub2
│   │       └── file3.hh
│   ├── qml
│   │   ├── file1.qml
│   │   └── sub1
│   │       ├── file2.qml
│   │       └── sub1.1
│   │           └── file3.qml
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── resources.qrc
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── sub1
│   │   │   ├── file1.cc
│   │   │   └── sub1.1
│   │   │       └── file2.cc
│   │   ├── sub2
│   │   │   └── file3.cc
│   │   └── Main.cc
│   └── webUtils
│       └── file.html
```

Comment: Set `ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS` for `android` in general and avoid setting `LiBS` in that way. Just put them in a local `lib` directory of the project.
Apart from that, did you add an AndroidManifest? That is probably missing and the required QML libs are not deployed to the device.

Comment: I have taken a qt5.4 starter project as example and it don't have an AndroidManifest. AndroidManifest is not automatically generated by qtcreator during the compilation?

Comment: Can you give me a link of a qt5.4 sample or github that have an Android Manifest?

Comment: As for the deploy, you can have a look [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-3.3/creator-deploying-android.html). Your Qt libs are not deployed: first of all have a look to `Projects > Build > Build Android APK` and ensure that `Build Qt libraries in APK` is checked.
In the same tab you have the `Create template` button which generates a manifest. Adding an icon for the app requires a custom manifest. Hence, creating it is necessary. Finally, the custom lib can be added via the `additional libraries` section in the same tab. I can provide an answer with `.pro` details if you want

Comment: If you can post an example of .pro and AndroidManifest files of a complex project with sub directories like mine (watch my question) could help me.

Comment: Sorry for the HUGE delay. Had a very busy week. Here is an example `pro` file. If you have doubts, questions or corrections feel free to ask. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example `.pro` file. I've scrapped out of too specific stuff. The directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── Project
│   ├── app.pro
|   ├── android
|   │   ├── res
|   |   │   ├── drawable-hdpi
|   |   |   └── ... 
|   |   ├── AndroidManifest 
│   ├── content
│   │   ├── file1.qml
│   │   └── ...
|   ├── icons
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── ...
|   ├── include
│   │   ├── sub1
│   │   │   ├── file1.hh
│   │   │   └── sub1.1
│   │   │       └── file2.hh
│   │   └── sub2
│   │       └── file3.hh  
|   ├── ios
|   |   └── Info.plist
|   ├── libs 
|   |   ├── droid
|   |   ├── ios
|   |   ├── macx  
|   |   ├── nix
|   |   ├── win
|   |   └── winphone
│   ├── Qml.qrc
|   ├── Resources.qrc 
|   ├── SubProject
|   ├── translations
|   |   ├── app_en.qm
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── [.cpp]
|   ├── [.h]
|   ├── app_en.ts
```

Differently from you I do not have a `src` dir and the `QML` files are moved to a `content` directory. I've also a resource file for the same `QML` files, i.e. `Qml.qrc`. Translation files (aka `.ts` files) are contained in the main dir with sources. The compiled translations (aka `.qm`) files are instead in the subdirectory `translations`.

The directory `android` and `ios` contain files specific to the platforms, in particular we have the [`res` directory](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) useful to provide an icon and a wallpaper to the app for the android platform. The same `android` dir is used as APK package source (see `.pro` below). The `ios` directory contains the [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html).

The `lib` directory contains a sub-dir for each platform with the recompiled library for that environment.

Here is the corresponding project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
macx:CONFIG += app_bundle

# QT IMPORT
QT += gui qml quick [...]

#include subproject
include(SubProject/subproject.pri)
# Default rules for deployment
include(deployment.pri)
# Compilation flags [specific to the different OSs]
include(flags.pri)

TARGET = "appName"  # just needed for me since I change target between "App" and "AppPRO"

INCLUDEPATH += [...]
    $$PWD/include/sub1 \
    $$PWD/include/sub2 

!isEmpty(QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH):LIBS += \
$$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH$${TOP_BUILD_DIR}/lib  #(UNIX ONLY): libs linked preferibly at runtime

# DESKTOP PLATFORMS
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/win/ -lLIBNAME1
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/win/ -lLIBNAMEd
unix:!macx:!ios:!android: LIBS  += -L$$PWD/lib/nix -lLIBNAME
macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/macx/ -lLIBNAME

# MOBILE PLATFORMS
ios: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ios -lLIBNAME
android: LIBS  += -L$$PWD/lib/droid -lLIBNAME
winphone: LIBS +=  -L$$PWD/lib/winphone/ -lLIBNAME
# ADDITIONAL ANDROID SETTING
ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS = $$PWD/lib/droid/libLIBNAME.so

# SOURCE FILES (.CPP)
SOURCES += [.cpp]

# HEADER FILES (.H)
HEADERS += [.h]

# objective-c++ sources for ios platform 
ios {
    QT += gui_private
    #QT -= printsupport
    HEADERS += [.h]
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += [.mm]
}

# QML sources are added here!
RESOURCES += Resources.qrc \
    Qml.qrc


# ANDROID ADDITION
android {
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android          # contains the dir structure of the APK, actually it contains just res
    OTHER_FILES += androidPro/AndroidManifest.xml       # <--- manifest for the Pro version
}



####  ICONS SECTION   ####
win32:RC_ICONS += $$ICON_PATH/multiIcon.ico   # ICONS for WIN
mac:!ios:ICON = $$ICON_PATH/icons.icns      # ICONS for MAC

#IOS BUNDLE                                 # ICONS for IOS
ios {
    BUNDLE_DATA.files = [...]
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += BUNDLE_DATA

QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = $$PWD/ios/Info.plist
}

# list QML sources for linguist purposes
lupdate_only{
SOURCES = *.qml \
          *.js \
          content/*.qml \
          content/*.js
}

# and the .ts file for translation!
TRANSLATIONS = app_en.ts \
               app_fr.ts \
               app_de.ts \
               app_sp.ts \
               app_en.ts
```

This is the `manifest`. Qt Creator allows editing via a UI interface or the textual editing. To add a manifest (Qt Creator 3.3), as stated in the comments, just go to `Projects > Build > Build Android APK > Create Templates`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="21" android:installLocation="auto" package="JAVA_PACKAGE" android:versionName="1.0.12" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation" android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:value="app" android:name="android.app.lib_name"/>
            <meta-data android:resource="@array/qt_sources" android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id"/>
            <meta-data android:value="default" android:name="android.app.repository"/>
            <meta-data android:resource="@array/qt_libs" android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id"/>
            <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_libs" android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --" android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib" android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id"/>
            <meta-data android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets" android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --" android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/" android:name="android.app.libs_prefix"/>
            <meta-data android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --" android:name="android.app.load_local_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --" android:name="android.app.load_local_jars"/>
            <meta-data android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --" android:name="android.app.static_init_classes"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <!-- Splash screen -->
            <meta-data android:resource="@drawable/splash" android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable"/>
            <!-- Splash screen -->
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```