# Unknown module in .pro file - cannot build app with androidextras module included

Tags: qt, installation, qtandroidextras

I am working on some Qt/QML app which will be deployed to Android OS. Now, I need module [`androidextras`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) but if I put `androidextras` inside my `.pro` file as follows

```
QT += qml quick widgets sql core bluetooth printsupport androidextras
```

and I rerun `qmake`, I get following error:

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: androidextras

I also tried to open and run the example project [Qt Notifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html) but the same error occurs so that I cannot build either my app or the example, which should have worked out of the box.

I am using `KUbuntu 15.04` with `gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13)` compiler and `Desktop Qt 5.5.0 GCC 64bit` Qt version. How do I build this `androidextras` module? 
I have `Android arm v7` kit  installed as you can see from the Maintenance Tool screenshot:

[image]

I've recompiled whole Qt with `clear && ./configure -opensource -confirm-license -verbose -cups -plugin-sql-mysql -android-sdk /opt/android-sdk-linux -android-ndk /opt/android-ndk-r10d && make && make install`, set up 
Qt version and Qt Kit in QtCreator, changed build kit and still same error pops up. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extras modules are meant to provide additional functions *specific* to a certain platform and thus available *only* on that platform. It could be the support to the badge number on iOS apps, the support to Windows jump lists or some utility functions to convert from a type to the corresponding platform native type (e.g. `QPixmap` to `CGImageRef`, again in Mac extras).

There exist four extras modules - [Win](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-index.html), [Mac/iOS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmacextras-index.html), [X11](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtx11extras-index.html), [Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html) - and as long as you compile for the *specific* chosen platform against the *specific* kit, everything is fine. And it's also automatic, for desktop environment: your host machine is always your target machine.

Mobile kits are instead used to cross-compile from a certain (desktop) host machine to another (mobile) target machine. In this settings you can easily (and erroneously) compile platform specific code with the wrong kit.

Generally speaking, you should put platform specific modules/code inside *conditionals* to ensure that it is compiled only against the specific kit for which they are available. That's especially true for software which must be compiled both for desktop and mobile platforms or across different desktop platforms. Conditional in `.pro` file could look like this:

```
android: QT += androidextras
mac: QT += macextras
// ...other platform specific and platform independent  settings
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28657759/2538363) for an android `.pro` example file which includes also manifest specific settings.

The same approach should be followed in code, i.e. check the OS and conditionally compile the platform code. For instance a multi-platform implementation of a function could look like this:

```
if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
#include <QtAndroid>
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#endif

// other code...

void YourClass::function()
{
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
// platform code
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN)

#endif
}
```

See for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29321247/2538363) for a complete Android example or [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32777398/2538363) for some useful iOS specific keywords.